# Eclipse: How to remove all TODO tagged comments?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, todo

In Eclipse, is there any way, e.g., built-in functionality or short cuts of Eclipse, to REMOVE ALL comments tagged with `TODO`?

So far I can click and open each file via the matched TODO items as shown in the picture, but it is impossible to finish all tasks manually if we have thousands of items. Looking for advice/help, Thanks!

[image]

Comment: *if we have thousands of items* - then you have a process problem, if there's so much technical debt.  How does code with "I don't understand this" ever get committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to:

1. Close the View and ignore it.
2. Find the **Task Tags** preference page for the language you're using, remove TODO from the list of tag words or modify it to be something more specific like "TODO: ahtasham".

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex to find and replace the characters with empty string,
to select any line containing TODO you can search for
REGEX:  (^.*TODO.+)
I am also attaching a screenshot of how to do it
[image]